# Marquee on web page reads text from textfile but displayed text is truncated

Tags: html, css, text-files

I have a marquee on a webpage which is receiving text from a text file. My issue is that the displayed text is truncated and I can't seem to modify any properties. Any idea how to allow for a longer text string to be displayed?

I have tried modifying CSS properties, including in Elements inspector, but nothing seems to change the text size or length of the field that it is displayed in.

```
<p><object type="text/html" data="marqueetext.txt"></object></p>
```

```
.marquee {
 height: 50px;  
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 background: black;
 color: #E9BF73;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size:medium ;
 border: 1px yellow;
}
.marquee p {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 /* Starting position */
 -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
 -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);    
 transform:translateX(100%);
 /* Apply animation */  
 -moz-animation: scroll-left 15s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: scroll-left 15s linear infinite;
 animation: scroll-left 15s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: Based on your html `<p><object type="text/html" data="marqueetext.txt"></object></p>` you haven't added the marquee class. Since your styles are for `.marquee p` you would want to update the css selector to be `p.marquee` to apply this to a paragraph tag with the marquee class (rather than a paragraph as a child of an element with class marquee) and add the class to your paragraph tag like so `<p class="marquee"><object type="text/html" data="marqueetext.txt"></object></p>`. Full disclosure, I haven't tested this but I believe it should work :)

Comment: Sorry yes this code is enclosed in the marquee class. Will try your suggestion thanks